# SaveAs file and then check whether it exists in directory or not

Tags: excel, vba

I have written below code to save a workbook and then to verify whether workbook saved successfully or not. To achieve this I want code to save file then go to its directory (where file is saved) and if file with same name exists (file save correctly in the desired directory) it displays message to confirm file saved successfully.
At presetting below code is saving the workbook successfully (any existing file gets overwritten(which the requirement) but it is not evaluating IF statement to true despite file saves correctly and exists in the directory it is going to else condition.

Please help to modify it....

```
Sub Submit()

Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String
path = "C:\REPORTS\"
filename1 = Range("B3").Value

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1 & " " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY") & ".xlsx", 
   FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Dim Fname As String
  Fname = filename1 & " " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY") & ".xlsx"
  MsgBox Fname

Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' If file save successfully IF will retrun true and message will be displayed
If fso.FileExists(path & Fname) = True Then
  MsgBox filename1 & " " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY") & ".xlsx" & " Saved Successfully"

Else
MsgBox "I reached Else"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Code is working for me even with `If fso.FileExists(path & Fname) = True Then` which could be shortened to `If fso.FileExists(path & Fname) Then`. Maybe whitespaces in B3 cause the issue?

Comment: what if there is already a file and you are not able to replace it because of say it is open then your if condition may not give you a correct picture?

Comment: Here is one way to do it **1.** Use `DIR` to check if the file exists. **2.** If file exists, check if the file if open/readonly **3.** if not read only use saveas and save **4.** Check the file modified date

Comment: @Siddarth Rout: In actual scenario file will be overwritten, so this is not a problem. And also lets take out the probability of it being open for now.

Comment: @storax it still is not working for me i have modified to remove the space from file name but still code is hitting else statement despite file saving successfully at given location. Is there any other way ?

Comment: What do you mean by other way? You could follow Siddharth's suggestion but that is something you do not want to do. I am just saying code is working for me. My suggestion now would be to step through the code and check at every step what is happening. Maybe you also turn on `DisplayAlerts` to see what is happening when saving the file.